# How to mix href and text in jstl?

Tags: jstl

I have a string which contains a multiple href links.

To output a single href using jstl I can use :

```
   <a href="<c:url value="www.google.com"/>">Google</a>
```

But what if there is a variable which contain a mix of text and href links, then the href is not displayed correctly. What is displayed is just actual href code with its text, the href is not rendered in the browser :

```
<c:out value="${mixOfHrefAndText}"/>
```

How can I dislay a block of text and href links using jstl where the text to be dislayed conains a mix of static text and href links ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the attribute `escapeXml` (by default it's true to escape special html characters):

```
<c:out value="..." escapeXml="false"/>
```

But be sure that the text does not contain any malicious code if you use `false`.